# Wrapping a string in a div in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in pure javascript to wrap a nacked string?

I have a string that I'm splitting based on a character to separate the header from the rest of the content. I would very much like to style that header, but i can't seem to find a good way to wrap a div around it with a class.

All I can seem to find is wrapping a div around something that already has other elements.

My code looks like this

```
var string = "Title*This is the very long content";
var title = string.split('*')[0]
var body = string.split('*')[1]

//put them back together
string = title + body;
```

Comment: [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), and then set the string value as a text node or inner text?  It's not really clear to me what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: If you are then calling `div.innerHTML = string`, I think what you want for the last line is something like`string = "<H1>" + title + "</H1><P>" + body + "</P>";`

Comment: @David, thank you. that's the push I needed. You know when you stare are something for too long? Yep, that's the case here :)

Answer (score 0):

> but i can't seem to find a good way to wrap a div around it with a
> class?

You can create an element *(which is at the end a tag HTML)* with [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
and attach it a class with [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

```js
let string = "Title*This is the very long content";
/*
let title = string.split('*')[0]
let body = string.split('*')[1]
*/
let [title, body] = string.split('*'); // Destructuring assignment


let headerTitle = document.createElement('h1');
headerTitle.textContent = title;
headerTitle.className = "red";//headerTitle.classList.add('red');


let bodyHTML = document.createElement('p');
bodyHTML.textContent = body;

document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = headerTitle.innerHTML +"<br/>"+ bodyHTML.innerHTML;
```

```css
.red{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" />
```

**Tip** Try to avoid `var` keyword for declaring variable and replace them with either `let` or `const` and better using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)